# WebDriver not taking url after browser launched

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have started learning Selenium WebDriver. I have noticed issue like given url not take after firefox browser launched. Please help with the resolution

WebDriver version: 2.53
Firefoxe  :48.0

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("www.google.com");
```

I see below error

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: ,"syncGUID":"0Sec7gq34_7U","location":"app-global","version":"48.0.2","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons"

Comment: Are you getting any particular error?

Comment: Yes. i see below error org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
,"syncGUID":"0Sec7gq34_7U","location":"app-global","version":"48.0.2","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the gecko dirver in the environment variables. You can get the exe from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

set it like this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("www.google.com");
}
```

or just add to you system environment variables

[image: Environment variables]

If you want to use another browser just replace the `gecko` with whatever browser you use. For chrome you would do `webdriver.chrome.driver`

[seleniumhq.org](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) has the exes for all the browsers supported by selenium

Comment: I am still seeing same issue

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Exec1 {
 
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/gecodriver/geckodriver-v0.19.0-win32/geckodriver.exe");
  
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  
  driver.get("www.google.com");
   
  
  
 }

}

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
,"syncGUID":"uT_r1jhJOwmV","location":"app-global","version":"48.0.2","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"a

Comment: Since it is windows, path is represented with backslash `"C:\\gecodriver\\geckodriver-v0.19.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe"` I'll update the answer

Comment: Does not work when running browser by setting system environment variables as per your image. Getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException:`. Any Suggestion

Comment: What message are you getting after`IllegalStateException`

Comment: Its "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases"

Comment: geckodriver-v0.19.0-win32 version am using currently.Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
,"syncGUID":"nogo66yxAg4E","location":"app-

Comment: geckodriver-v0.19.0-win32